# A basic java program that wasn't compiled

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I've written the below code, but because of an error, it wasn't complied successfully. Please advise! The error says "error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to boolean" as well as "error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to double".

```
class BMITest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showData(fullName("John", "McDermott"), 178, 74.3);
}

    public static void showData(String name, double height, double weight) {
        double bmi = BMInum(height, weight);
        System.out.println("His name is " + name + ", and his BMI is " + bmi);

        if (isHealthy(bmi)) {
            System.out.println("He is healthy.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("He's not healthy.");
        }
    }

    public static String fullName(String first, String last) {
        return first + " " + last;
    }

    public static double BMInum(double height, double weight) {
        return weight / height / height * 10000;
    }

    public static double isHealthy(double bmi) {
        return bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25.0;
    }


}
```

Comment: `isHealthy` should have a `boolean` return type instead of `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `isHealthy` method to

```
public static boolean isHealthy(double bmi) {
    return bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isHealthy returns a double and not a boolean. Since you use it in an if-statement theat is required.